# Applying Grayscale in Google Map Terrain Only

Tags: google-maps

I tried doing a Google Map with multiple marker, it works without applying the Google Map style but when i set the background to grayscale it does not seem to display the map. I would like to maintain the marker colored so CSS styling is not an option. The code can be seen below

```
function initialize() {

  // Create an array of styles.
  var styles = [
    {
      stylers: [

        { saturation: -20 }
      ]
    }
  ];

 var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: "Styled Map"});

    var locations = [
      ['United States', 38.976492, -103.875732, 3],
      ['Europe', 54.747569, 112.421105,346.289063, 3]

    ];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.92, 1.25),
      mapTypeId: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
     map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code is wrong, it will prevent the map from loading:

```
mapTypeId: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
```

`mapTypeId` has to be exactly 1 valid `mapType`, not an array .
You may remove this line completely.

When you want to draw the controls for these mapTypes, you must set the `mapTypeIds`-option of the `mapTypeControlOptions`-property instead:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.92, 1.25),
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
       mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
      }
     });
```

your map should be displayed now with the 2 desired `mapType`-controls.

To apply a grayscale set the `saturation` to `-100`